# single positional indexer is out-of-bounds.....for-loop problem

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I have tried to run a for loop over a dataframe. Loop was running okay but while taking the output it's giving an error ..
IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds

my code is as follows......

```
def ce_buy_sell(df):
    ce_buy = []
    ce_sell = []
    flag = -1
    for i in range(0, len(df)):
        precondition = (df['Low'].iloc[i+1] > df['Low'].iloc[i+2]) and (df['High'].iloc[i+1] < df['High'].iloc[i+2])
        if precondition == True and  df['High'].iloc[i] > df['High'].iloc[i+1]:
            ce_sell = ""
            if flag != 1:
                ce_buy = (df['Close'].iloc[i])
                flag = 1
            else:
               ce_sell = ""
        elif df['Low'].iloc[i] < df['Low'].iloc[i+1]:
            ce_buy =""
            if flag != 0:
                ce_sell = (df['Close'].iloc[i])
                flag = 0
            else:
                ce_buy = ""
        else:
            ce_buy =""
            ce_sell =""

    return(ce_buy, ce_sell)

a = ce_buy_sell(df)
df['CE Buy'] = a[0]
df['CE Sell'] = a[1]
```

Please give me some solution.

Comment: Have you tried doing a `print(len(df))` and seeing what that gives you?

Comment: Do remember that ```df.iloc[:, i+1]``` would refer to the ```i+2``` column. This type of error occurs because of wrong column number count.

Comment: @JosipJuros yes ..print(len(df)) is giving...377. in my dataset first row is the latest row. In that case how can i solve this?

Comment: You compare the n-th element to the next two or wahtever, so ofc when you get to the last one you are trying to compare that last one to elements that doesnt exist. You need to not use `i+1` and `i+2`. Or add a check that makes sure elements on that index exist or are no `null`

Comment: Then can I use ...for i in range (0, len(df)-2)?

Answer (score 0):

you use "i+1" may be larger or equal len(df), which is out of bounds, you should c

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Then how can i solve this?....first row is the latest row in my database.

Answer (score 0):

Obvious issue is that you run out of rows/cells. You use both `i+1` and `i+2` Without a check, so when you reach the final 2 for loop passes, the precondition throws an error that its out of range, because it is. Either change that precondition or add a check function that makes sure the index doesnt go out of bounds. How you implement this is up to you depending on what you do in the for loop itself.